# TFS Kanban board filter

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

For the Kanban board (the one that is displaying the Stories or the Features) I'd like to include only the items from the current iteration.

It's possible to filter this board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent updates to TFS 2015 include some of these capabilities.  See [Filter Kanban Board](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/filter-kanban-board#text-filter) on MSDN for details on what is supported.

**Original Post:**

No, it's impossible. For now, kanban board has no filtering capability.

This have been a feature request in uservoice. And get a start response for PM.

> [Provide filtering options for the Kanban board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11349897-provide-filtering-options-for-the-kanban-board)
>
> We are adding the
> ability to filter the board on any field. We expect to deliver this in
> Q2 2016.
>
> Sandeep Chadda
> Program Manager

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2017 has some nice filter capabilities.
On the main page of the kanban board you can filter by Keyword, Item type, Assigned to, Tags, Iteration or Parent work item.